# datatables modifying cells based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

So i am trying to modify a column based on the cell value but for some reason it is not working. This is part of what I have so far..

```
"createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
          if( data[3] == 'N')
          {
            $('td', row).eq(3).addClass('highlight');
          }
          console.log(data[3]);
        },

        "sAjaxSource": "GetJSONData",
```

For some reason it is not working, if i remove the the if statement it does highlight all the rows in one column. But i only want the N values. When i type

```
console.log(data[3]);
```

in the console on developers tools i get undefined

Just fyi i am using datatables 1.10.6 and codeigniter

Comment: The only reason for this not to work is, that you dont have any columns(3) holding the value `'N'`.

Comment: post your full code, are you earlier during columns.data setting your columns numerically or by field name  ? for ex: columns : [
    { data: 'entity_id' },